# Center a note in a measure

Tags: lilypond

I'm creating a fingering chart where I would like to center notes in a measure, like the picture below. How would I do that?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to adjust the x-offset of the notes like this:

```
\version "2.24.3"

\layout {
  ragged-right = ##f
}

\relative { 
  \override NoteColumn.X-offset = 6
  cis'1 | d | ees | e 
}
```

There is probably a better way, but that will work.